# Using NAudio to convert an online radio stream to PCM, in real-time

Tags: naudio

Could NAudio be used to convert a radio-stream to PCM samples, in real-time?
I've seen documentation and questions regarding conversion of local audio-files, but did not find reference to *real-time* conversion of an *online* (radio) stream.

*My current specific interest is in a ShoutCAST MP3 stream.*

*Solution is to embedded in a Winforms application written using VB.Net. Target OS is Windows 7.*

Your assistance would be much obliged.

Comment: perhaps you could ask the developer(s) themselves, on CodePlex

Comment: Thanks @WimOmbelets. The main developer - Mark Heath - suggests on the NAudio site to send questions here. I should probably try CodePlex as well, as you suggested.

Comment: which operating systems and codecs, your application should support?

Comment: App should support a ShoutCAST MP3 stream.
It's a Winforms application written using VB.Net. Target OS is Windows 7.

Comment: You should be able to feed the MP3 frames from the ShoutCAST stream into one of the MP3 frame decompressors in NAudio.  Is that what you're after?

Comment: Possibly, if through that I'd be able to acquire stream PCM-samples on real-time. Could you suggest a VB/C# code-sample showing how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer by Mark Heath, on CodePlex:

**Regarding MP3 Streams:**
hi, have a read of my blog post here about streaming MP3: http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/how-to-play-back-streaming-mp3-using.html.
To calculate power, you'd examine the PCM sample values after decompressing, and perform your own calculations.

**Regarding ShoutCAST Streams:**
*NAudio does not decode Shoutcast* at the moment.

***Even so, if someone does have a solution for ShoutCAST streams, I'd appreciate it if you post it here.***